# Android application to see the total CPU time for each application

Tags: android

I'm looking for a Android application that can

- display the total CPU time for each application since the last reboot, just like Windows' task manager display  the total CPU time for each program:

[image]

And if possible:

- free
- doesn't take too much CPU
- has as many other stats as possible (IO, RAM, process path, threads, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

There is an Android Application named [SystemPanel App / Task Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.systempanel.r1).

SystemPanel includes the following features:

- Task Manager: The task manager shows what applications are currently loaded into memory and/or running on a device, including current CPU and memory utilization for each. The task manager provides the ability to kill offending applications, and includes an emergency "end all" widget to handle extreme scenarios.
- System Monitor: The system monitor can be enabled to record device usage history over a period of time (up to one week), such that you can determine what applications and usage patterns have the greatest impact on battery life. This feature is commonly used to help track down which applications are having major negative effects on battery life. The system monitor records CPU usage for each process, overall CPU usage, display usage, battery level, and battery charging status.
- Installer: The installer enables you to install and uninstall applications quickly and conveniently. It can archive multiple versions of applications, such that you can backup your apps before an update and revert back to older versions afterward. This is useful in the not uncommon event the updated item is buggy or otherwise undesirable. Additionally, the Installer is designed to work much more efficiently than the standard Android application manager, and does not suffer the frustrating lag issues found in the default Android item when browsing through a large number of installed apps.

You can see your CPU usage by application in following screen. Note you need to check the show app CPU time option in the settings:

> [image] [image]
>   <sup>usage by application in following screen / check the show app CPU time option (click images for larger variants)</sup>

PS: This is not a free application ( since your requirement is *if possible* ).

For free version you can try this lite version [SystemPanelLite Task Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.systempanel).

Comment: Great app, thanks! I installed it and it works great. Do you know by any chance if there is a way to sort by CPU time?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, Sorry, No idea at present.

Answer (score 4):

I use [Wakelock Detector-Save Battery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector.noroot)

- free
- display the total CPU time for each application
- doesn't take too much CPU
- can order by total CPU time
- can show both app that use CPU time, and app that turn on the screen
- can show the app that use a "wake up" trigger

It's very usefull to fnd out which app/service are eating the battery

Here are some screenshot from my phone.

**The CPU utilization time from last reboot / The details of a single app:**
[image: Cpu time utilization from last reboot] [image: single app details with function name that use Cpu]
<sup>(click images for larger variants)</sup>

(Google Services in the image, that continue to eat my battey no matter what I do :-| )

**Some useful link to the app information / Some totals**
[image: links to the app] [image: awake/sleep totals]
<sup>(click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: Welcome on Software Recommendation. Your post hasn't the minimum quality requirement for SR. Please read [this meta post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality) about minimum answer's quality requirement, and then improve your post.

Comment: @Fractaliste thanks for the advice, now I'm a bit short on time, but this night I'll try to edit the answer to make it respect the SR gudeline

Comment: @Max Another awesome app, and free, thanks Max!

Comment: @Max the link for the app either is broken or the app doesn't exist anymore: "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server."

Answer (score 1):

[System Panel 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.sp)

This will replacing the System Panel Task Manager and SystemPanelLite Task Manager both mentioned [in this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2528/30736).

[image]

Note that

> Android 7 and later versions deliberately restrict users from seeing what applications are running on their devices for security reasons. You can enable "Enhanced Statistics" by connecting this device to a computer to grant developer permissions.

Comment: Thanks I'm curious to know what's the security reason they're talking about!